# Error ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR with TravelItineraryAddInfo Sabre

Tags: sabre

I want call `TravelItineraryAddInfo` to add passenger to PNR, but api return error `ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR , ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE.`
How can I fix this issue ?

**My request**

```
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2016-05-17T15:30:00-06:00" Version="2.2.0" ReturnHostCommand="false">
<AgencyInfo>
    <Address>
        <AddressLine>xxxx</AddressLine>
        <CityName>xxx</CityName>
        <CountryCode>XX</CountryCode>
        <PostalCode>xxxx</PostalCode>
        <StateCountyProv StateCode="xx"/>
        <StreetNmbr>xx</StreetNmbr>
    </Address>
</AgencyInfo>
<CustomerInfo>
    <ContactNumbers>
        <ContactNumber InsertAfter="0" LocationCode="VN" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="984163620" PhoneUseType="H"/>
    </ContactNumbers>
    <Email Address="xxx@gmail.com" LanguageOverride="O" NameNumber="1.1" Type="CC"/>
    <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1"  PassengerType="ADT">
        <GivenName>Smith</GivenName>
        <Surname>TEST</Surname>
    </PersonName>
</CustomerInfo>
```

**This is response api:**

```
<stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    <stl:Message>.ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
```

Comment: Can you try without InsertAfter and LanguageOverride. Also I think the LocationCode on contact is of 3 character.

Comment: yeah, i 'm tried without InsertAfter and LanguageOverride, and changed LocationCode="KUL", but the response returned:  ENTRY VALID ONLY FOR SUBSCRIBER PNR, ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE. what the field is not correct?

Comment: StreetNumber should start with numeric value. If it still does not go through, you will have to contact sabre support. I think you might have to enable some feature on TJR

Comment: Has a ticket been issued already? Do you try to make a name change? Is the name the same as in the pnr you try to modify?

Comment: Would you mind to describe the sequence step by step that are you calling till this point, I mean the whole process and please confirme if you are using the same EPR/Credential to create the sessions for each process and please be aware about the Duty code/Permissions configured in your credential (EPR), because to do some operations your credential must be configured to do it.

Comment: It throws the same error when I tried to add contact number, email id and some names. But removing NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" worked.